# floating hint text not disappear after typing something

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, hint

i want to make a register fragment with text input layout. But my problem is hint property. when typing, hint's copy goes up. I have two hints when typing.And also I don't have this problem in activity page. How can i solve this in fragment?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNZPU.jpg

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FloatingHintStyle">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Emailinizi giriniz"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FloatingHintStyle">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Şifrenizi giriniz"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Its an intended functionality, it moves to the top to let the know the user whats the field without having to add a textview or something else as a title for the editText, if you want the hint to go up and disappear from where the user is typing use the answer below, if you dont the hint to move whatsoever dont use textinputlayout.

Comment: I want to use textinputlayout with floating hint property. but it is not working in fragment. when i copy code and paste it to the activity, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`, your code should be like

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/floating_hint_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Emailinizi giriniz"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/floating_hint_pass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Şifrenizi giriniz"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: in the picture, third edittext writes "email", it made with TextInputEditText. the problem is in fragment. hint stays when typing